# How to import Pandas data frames in a loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, global-variables, assign

I have N .txt files in my working directory that I need to import as pandas dataframe.
My elementary code :

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(File1.txt)
...
dataN = pd.read_csv(FileN.txt)
```

I want to import it in one go. I simply thought about a `for` loop.

My questions are :

1) How to affect a variable name depending on the index `i` (see code below)

2) Is it a bad idea ? If yes, why and what are the better ways of doing it ?

If `my_datas_names` is the list of the files name,

```
for i in my_data_names:
   dataframe(i) = pd.read_csv(data_lst_names[i])
```

where I don't know how to properly write `dataframe(i)` so that Python creates variables called `dataframe1`, ...,`dataframeN`.

Thanks for your answers,

Comment: `from pathlib import Path`;`text_files = {file.stem : pd.read_csv(file) for file in Path('location\of\txt\file').glob('*.txt')}` see marked duplicated

Comment: Yes it seems it does, thank you !

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as duplicated :) good luck